# Why CMD is running while Spyder is open within Anaconda?

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, spyder

I have recently updated Anaconda and Spyder.

However, once I opened Spyder within Anaconda, I got an issue with Spyder.

Command Prompt (cmd) is running while I open Spyder (picture is attached).[image]

The problem is that when I close the cmd window Spyder is crashing.

Can someone help me with fixing this issue?

Thanks

P.S. I have to note that no similar issue is noticed when Spyder is running not within Anaconda

Comment: Spider is running inside cmd. Shutting down cmd will shut down all it's child processes including spider

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Why is it a problem? There are many programs that open a CMD window. Just ignore it

Comment: When I open solely spyder cmd window is not appearing ... but with Anaconda it does)

Comment: It is a new feature? Or is it a issue? In the old version, this windows did not appear.

Comment: I have this problem too. Spyder can run normally. It is just that the occurrence of such a cmd window is quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Detach the Spyder process from the console. On windows, this can be accomplished with the command **start**.
`start \path_to_python\Scripts\spyder.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Reset the configuration:
File > Preferences > Configure navegator / Configure conda > Reset to defaults

If you have "Kite" installed, try to remove it. And Reset again